# yadcf by name or data-* not column_number

Tags: yadcf

I am trying to set a `range_date` on a column using yadcf plugin for datatables, however, all the examples are using the `column_number` but my columns can shift so wondering if I can set by any other attribute I can set on the `<th>`?

Consider the following:

```
yadcf.init(table, [
    {
        column_number: 13,
        filter_type: "range_date",
        date_format: "dd//mm/yyyy",
        filter_delay: 500
    }
]);
```

Comment: if you're talking about colredorder know that yaadcf support it out of the box

Comment: Yes I do know that thanks @Daniel. In that logic, if you change the order of the columns, does column_number: 13 stick with the newly positioned column?

Comment: it wont, but If you will pass your data from server to the original column 13 it will go into that column in its new position,